# dynamic page not indexed

Tags: plugins, search

Im writting a plugin who makes dynamic pages with simple page template:

http://domain.com/slug

the url is rewriting so internally call to http://domain.com/index.php?pagename=users

and works, but the problem is, how I can index it to make searches?

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean internal searches? or a google index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have at least have a  link to the query url somewhere on your public pages ?

Google does follow query parameters, so that will at least bring it to the crawlers attention.

See http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/improved-handling-of-urls-with.html

(I almost have the opposite with my event/calendar plugin.  google is paying almost too  much attention to the pages and their date query parameters (moving forward in time etc).  See notes on that here http://icalevents.com/4046-google-indexing-bandwidth-and-calendar-parameters/  )

Other good seo stuff will then help.  Sitemaps etc

Also see if you can improve the markup on the page - if about people, then maybe some people microdata will help google index the page .(my plugin's html does event rich snippets) see Rich snippets - People:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146646